# before offices turned en masse to remote working

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Slack’s share price struggled to recover from the drubbing it received after the company’s quarterly earnings disappointed investors. **Revenue was up by 50% year on year, but that was only a slight improvement in growth on the previous quarter, before offices turned en masse to remote working.**

---

What does the sentence mean, especially which does "before offices turned en masse to remote working" modify?

- 1. revenue was up by 50% just before offices turned en masse to remote working?
- 2. on the previous quarter which was before offices turned en masse to remote working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter. The *before* clause modifies *the previous quarter*. To get your other reading, *but ... quarter* would have to be in parentheses, and so outside the syntax of the main sentence.